# How to use SIP (voip) into my application to make video calls in Iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I need to use SIP(VoIP) in my applications can anyone suggest me how to start with this with an sample code in objective-c or sequence of steps to do.

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.
Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[www.voipcore.com](http://www.voipcore.com)

Comment: Thanks for your link I known so many things which I dont know from this link.But I need a suggestion to how to use it in my Iphone app.

Answer (score 1):

There is one iPhone app which is known as linephone and it's source code is also available at [here](http://www.linphone.org/eng/download/git.html) .This app is using SIP(VoIP).